# How to create from nested lambda expression Functor classes

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

I have started to learn about lambda expressions and  nested lambda expressions:

```
    auto Suma=[](int x)->function<int(int)>
    {
        return [x](int y)
        {
            return x+y;
        };
    };
    auto Mult=[](function<int(int)>&f, int z)
    {
        return f(z)*2;
    };
```

I would like to create 3 Functor classes (for better understanding how it works), it should be 3 classes Sum, Inner and Mult.

**.h:**

```
    class Suma
    {
    public:
        int operator()(int x);
    };

    class Inner
    {
        Suma function;
    public:
        Inner(int x);
        int operator()(int k);
    };
    class Mult
    {
    public:
        int operator()(Suma function,int z);

    };
```

**.cpp:**

```
int Suma::operator()(int x)
{
return x;
}

Inner::Inner(int x)
{
    function.operator()(x);
}
int Inner::operator()(int k)
{
    return function.operator()+k;
}

int Mult::operator()(Suma function,int z)
{
    return (function.operator())*(2);
}
```

The main issue I face is when trying to include the function from one related class to another. I dont fully understand the main idea of how it is connected through classes. Could please advice me how should it work.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: LogicStuff   I dont understand how they are connected through classes. Cause the realisation of lambdas is done through it... thats why I ask how it should look like in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes do not reflect the structure of the lambdas.

The inner lambda returns a function with adds its paramter to the capture. 
So your `Inner` class shall not depend on `Suma`, and be defined as follows:

```
// definition in .h
    class Inner
    {
        int myx; 
    public:
        Inner(int x);    // this represents the capture of the lambda
        int operator()(int k);  // this is the function of adding k to the catpture
    };

// implementation in .cpp
    Inner::Inner(int x) 
    {
        myx = x; 
    }
    int Inner::operator()(int k)
    {
        return myx + k;
    }
```

The Suma shall then return an `Inner` with an x set:

```
// definition in .h
    class Suma
    {
    public:
        Inner operator()(int x);
    };

// implementation in .cpp
    Inner Suma::operator()(int x) 
    {
        return Inner(x); 
    };
```

With your lambdas, when you evaluate `Suma(3)`, you'll obtain a function that takes an integer and adds 3 to it.  If you evaluate `Suma(3)(2)` you therefore get 5.

With the classes emulating the lambdas, you would then do the same:

```
Suma f;  // that is an object, like "auto suma"
cout << f(3)(2) <<endl;   // f(3) is in fact an object Inner(3) wich is then exectued with argument 2.
```

Here you have an **[online demo](http://ideone.com/pjTfkD)**.

You could even be closer to the structure of your lambdas by having `Inner` be a nested class of `Suma`.

Now looking at the `Mult` class, it appears that the first argument is not a `Suma` object,  but the result of an invocation to `Suma` (i.e. return type of its operator()) .   So it's an `Inner`.  Hence, you can complete the code as follows:

```
// definition in .h 
    class Mult {
    public:
        int operator()(Inner& function, int z);
    };
// implementation in .cpp
    int Mult::operator()(Inner& function, int z)
    {
        return (function(z))*(2);  // funtion(z) means function.operator()(z)
    }
```

By the way, as you see above, you don't need to explicitely call operator(): just provide the arguments between parenthesis.

Comment: Christophe , Thanks  alot, but it doesnt work(((  there are errors:   Error 254 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: @Melany I've edited with a couple of extra explanation and a link to an online code.

Comment: @Melany I've tested the online code in MSVC: it works as well without error.  However, your Mult is flawed and causes errors.  So I've edited my answer to explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really maked it clear for me. It really helped,Ones again Thank you!!!